# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngCsvProvider <- ngCsv <- dynamicDemoController

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

Here is my scenario:

- file **A.js** that define the main module.
- file **B.js** lazy-loaded (after angular bootstrap) that contains a controller and some directives.

file **A.js**:

```
var APP = angular.module('app.hello', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTable', 'ngSanitize', 'ngCsv']);

(function() {

  APP.config(function ($controllerProvider, $compileProvider) {
    APP.loadController = $controllerProvider.register;
    APP.loadDirective = $compileProvider.directive;
  });

})();
```

file **B.js**:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  APP.loadController("dynamicDemoController", dynamicDemoController);
  dynamicDemoController.$inject = ["NgTableParams", "ngCsv"]; // <-- err

  function dynamicDemoController(NgTableParams, CSV) {
   // ...
  }

})();
```

I'm injecting `NgTableParams` flawlessly but I'm not being able to "inject" the `ngCsv` module and I'm getting this error in console:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngCsvProvider <- ngCsv <-
>   dynamicDemoController

Any idea what am I possibly missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to inject a module in your `controller`, that's why its causing error.

```
  dynamicDemoController.$inject = ["NgTableParams", "ngCsv"]; // <-- err
```

`ngCsv` is a `module` and not a `service`.

Loading of module's should be limited to `angular.module`.

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ngCsv'])
```

Comment: What could be the solution then? Referring to the ngCsv documentation, ngCsv should expose a "service": https://github.com/asafdav/ng-csv/wiki/Using-CSV-as-Service an they're using it on a controller.

Comment: Just inject CSV... not ngCsv... when you load the ngCsv module, you also get the CSV service too..

Comment: the module holds this service, https://github.com/asafdav/ng-csv/blob/master/src/ng-csv/services/csv-service.js